# Unit test Haxe when targeting PHP

Tags: unit-testing, haxe

I will use Haxe and the PHP target to develop a blog system. I would like to write it using TDD. Naturally I will use a database. How can it be done?

Comment: Any feedback on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working setup](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/cagette-trial/commit/0fb27126305b14bf64b6a413652d11f662146d2a) using `MassiveUnit` I did for a pet project:

```
./backend/
├── build.hxml
├── Dockerfile
├── src
│   ├── Main.hx
│   └── Stats.hx     # unit under test
├── test
│   ├── StatsTest.hx # a simple test case
│   ├── TestMain.hx  # tests runner
│   └── TestSuite.hx # collect tests to execute
└── test.hxml
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, its from the old docs, but still relevant http://old.haxe.org/doc/cross/unit

There are nice libraries for it too, like https://github.com/massiveinteractive/MassiveUnit/